# cron jobs with django.core.management

Tags: python, django, cron

In a project, a guy (travelling now) created the `cron.py` with the content

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.core import management


def hourly():
    management.call_command(
        'transactions',
        check_completed=True,
        verbosity=0,
        interactive=False)


def deposits():
    management.call_command(
        'transactions',
        deposits=True,
        push=True,
        verbosity=0,
        interactive=False)


def debit():
    management.call_command(
        'transactions',
        debits=True,
        push=True,
        verbosity=0,
        interactive=False)
```

Could anyone be able to tell me what are `hourly()`, `deposits()` and `debit()`? How could we use that for a cron job? It seems he used that for cron jobs, but it is unclear for me.

Thanks!

Comment: check your installed apps. Is there a django_crontab or something similar  to cron ? If so this is a cron job settings that is scheduled to run daily/hourly, etc..

Comment: In fact, the only thing I have related to it is when I execture `./manage.py` in the terminal, there is a management command called ` cron`. Is it what you meant?

Comment: Yes, Most likely it is this app in action: https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab

Comment: Yes, but this is not installed in the setting.py.